# Why (and what influence does it have) one has to select type of project in xcode->mac os x-> command line tool?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, command-line-tool

While creating a command line tool (Mac OS X) project in XCode, one has to select "type" of project out of these options :-

1.Foundation
2.Core Services
3.Core Foundation
4.C
5.C++

Question is : WHY such selection and how it influences? Can't I create a normal objective C program just like we create a cpp or c file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you can create an Objective-C program like a normal C or C++ program, it's just that, with Objective-C there are extra libraries you might want to link with and extra header files.

Each of those options uses a different project template with different compiler settings, different linked frameworks and libraries and different header files.  If you want to build a straight no frills Objective-C program but that still uses things like NSObject, use "Foundation" and you will automatically get a main.m file and compiler and linker settings for the Foundation framework.

Comment: I am little confused that " without one of these frameworks, lone  objective-c has no meaning".
and C, C++ means syntax can also be of these two language rather than Objective C or .... otherwise

Comment: @user1085822: You can use Objective-C without the Foundation framework,  but you would have to create your own class hierarchy.  You'd need your  own equivalent to NSObject, NSString etc.

Answer (score 1):

The various options you list determine what project template is used for you. This means, e.g., which frameworks are linked in by default and other compiler settings.

To create a "meaningful" Objective C project, you need at least to include the Foundation framework, since it is there that the `NSObject` class resides (and it is the main "interface" to the ObjC runtime).

If you would like to go *without* `NSObject`, you would need to implement basic things related to the ObjC runtime in your objects. Take a look at [this post from S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835704/how-to-create-a-root-object-in-objective-c-without-nsobject) for more info on this.

Hope it helps.